# Mixing fPIC and non-fPIC object modules

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, shared-libraries, position-independent-code

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04

In my experiment, I ran the following commands:

```
gcc -c 1.c
gcc -c -fPIC 2.c
gcc -shared 1.o 2.o -o libmyxxx.so
```

The functions that I need to expose are all defined in 2.c via `extern "C"` declarations. These functions internally call other functions that are defined in 1.c.

Note that I did not apply `-fPIC` to 1.c. Still everything seems to compile/link fine without any warnings.

Can we conclude that `-fPIC` must be applied only to those source files that expose external functions?

In the larger picture, I have a bunch of archive (.a) files that may not have been compiled with `-fPIC` flag. I need to create a custom shared library that would link with these archive files. If my assumption is valid, I am thinking it would be okay to link with these archive files. Appreciate your thoughts. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we conclude that -fPIC must be applied only to those source files
>   that expose external functions?

No we can't. The only purpose of `-fPIC` is ensure that produced machine code can be linked into position-independent binary. Nevertheless it is possible that some code appears to be PIC-ready even if source was compiled without `-fPIC`. It may be short self-containing functions without external dependencies, whatever that will not require auxiliary data structures in generated object file, like PLT and GOT entries.

Anyway linker will fail with comprehensive error message if your object file cannot be linked into position-independent binary. And you need to recompile it with this magic option.

So you should always put `-fPIC` to `CFLAGS` of your shared library just to save your own time and avoid wasteful recompilations.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more in which case it will fail to link a non-PIC .o into .so? At least the case in this question doesn't have this issue. But I once hit such linking issues.

Comment: @xnervwang Try to play with objects that reference external global data objects.

Comment: @xnervwang Try to play with objects that reference external global data objects.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an object file in the executable, that is compiled without -fPIC flag, there will be pages of program text that have *position dependent memory references*. These pages won't be able to be relocated to suitable virtual memory addresses at run time (which is mostly the purpose of shared objects). When you build your code on some other machine or link the .so to some other code, these *position dependent memory references* will come and bite you.

-fPIC is required to generate position independent code for:

- global variables
- static variables
- external variables
- string constants
- taking addresses of the function

Also, you might get away without any warning or error when compiling/linking an object file without -fPIC on Linux/x86-32; but it is impossible to do that on some architectures.